# How do I perform HTML Validation without adding JavaScript validation variables?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I searched around the site for this question but was unable to find the answer I needed. I am making a form that produces a grade percentage and a letter grade based on user input.

However, I also need to validate the form. Currently, the calculation function works fine but the HTML code does not validate before submitting, so a user can submit anything and it will still run. Is there an easy I can validate without making JavaScript validation variables?

Thank you!!

HTML:

```
<p><b>Name: </b> <input type="text" size="20" id="student" required><span class="required">*</span></p>

<p><b>Assignment 1: </b><input type="number" id="assign1" size=10 value="" name="onlynumbers" min="0" max="25" required><span class="required">*</span></p>

<p><b>Assignment 2: </b><input type="number" id="assign2" size=10 value="" name="onlynumbers" min="0" max="25" required><span class="required">*</span></p>

<p><b>Assignment 3: </b><input type="number" id="assign3" size=10 value="" name="onlynumbers" min="0" max="25" required><span class="required">*</span></p>

<p><b>Assignment 4: </b><input type="number" id="assign4" size=10 value="" name="onlynumbers" min="0" max="25" required><span class="required">*</span></p>

<p><b>Midterm Exam: </b><input type="number" id="midterm" size=10 value="" name="onlynumbers" min="0" max="100" required><span class="required">*</span></p>

<p><b>Final Exam: </b><input type="number" id="final" size=10 value="" name="onlynumbers" min="0" max="100" required><span class="required">*</span></p>

<p><b>Final Project: </b><input type="number" id="project" size=10 value="" name="onlynumbers" min="0" max="100" required=""><span class="required">*</span></p>

<p>
<button onclick="calculator()">Submit</button>

<input type="reset" value="Reset">

</p>
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
    function calculator()
    {
        var student=document.getElementById('student').value;
        var grade1=parseFloat(document.getElementById('assign1').value*1);
        var grade2=parseFloat(document.getElementById('assign2').value*1);
        var grade3=parseFloat(document.getElementById('assign3').value*1);
        var grade4=parseFloat(document.getElementById('assign4').value*1);
        var grade5=parseFloat(document.getElementById('midterm').value*1);
        var grade6=parseFloat(document.getElementById('final').value*1);
        var grade7=parseFloat(document.getElementById('project').value*1);
        var total=grade1 + grade2 + grade3 + grade4 + grade5 + grade6 + grade7;
        var average = total / 4

        document.getElementById('average').innerHTML = average;



        if ( average < 59.9 )
              document.writeln("<h1>Hello "+ student +", your grade percent is " + average +"%, and your letter grade is F.</h1>" );

            else if (average <= 63.9 && average >= 60 )
              document.writeln("<h1>Hello, "+ student +", your grade percent is " + average +"%, and your letter grade is D-.</h1>" );

            else if( average <= 66.9 && average >= 64 )
              document.writeln("<h1>Hello "+ student +", your grade percent is " + average +"%, and your letter grade is D.</h1>" );                        

            else if( average <= 69.9 && average >= 67 )
              document.writeln("<h1>Hello "+ student +", your grade percent is " + average +"%, and your letter grade is D+.</h1>" );

            else if( average <= 73.9 && average >= 70 )
              document.writeln("<h1>Hello "+ student +", your grade percent is " + average +"%, and your letter grade is C-.</h1>" );  

            else if( average <= 76.9 && average >= 74 )
              document.writeln("<h1>Hello "+ student +", your grade percent is " + average +"%, and your letter grade is C.</h1>" );

            else if( average <= 79.9 && average >= 77 )
              document.writeln("<h1>Hello "+ student +", your grade percent is " + average +"%, and your letter grade is C+.</h1>" );

            else if( average <= 83.9 && average >= 80 )
              document.writeln("<h1>Hello "+ student +", your grade percent is " + average +"%, and your letter grade is B-.</h1>" );

            else if( average <= 86.9 && average >= 84 )
              document.writeln("<h1>Hello "+ student +", your grade percent is " + average +"%, and your letter grade is B.</h1>" );

            else if( average <= 89.9 && average >= 87 )
              document.writeln("<h1>Hello "+ student +", your grade percent is " + average +"%, and your letter grade is B+.</h1>" );

            else if( average <= 93.9 && average >= 90 )
              document.writeln("<h1>Hello "+ student +", your grade percent is " + average +"%, and your letter grade is A.</h1>" );

            else if( average <= 100 && average >= 94 )
              document.writeln("<h1>Hello "+ student +", your grade percent is " + average +"%, and your letter grade is A+.</h1>" );

    }
```

Comment: just iterate over all your inputs and check their values in the loop

Comment: If you've figured it out, then either post an answer to your own question with what you did so that others who come across this will benefit from your solution or up vote the answers given  here that helped you and mark one of them as "the" answer.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I thought I figured it out so I was modifying the code with the answer but it turns out it didn't actually work when I tried it again, dang.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [HTML form validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation) attributes that don't require any JavaScript at all:

```html
<form action="#" method="post">
  <input name="test" required>
  <input name="ssNumber" pattern="d{3}-d{2}-d{4}" required>
  <input type="email" required>
  <div>
    <button>Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Or, you can just loop over the HTML form fields in JavaScript and check them individually.

However, whatever you do, **you must understand and any client-side validation technique can easily be bypassed** and so any client-side validations should be done again on the server, after the data has been submitted.

Now, you have several other problems with your code that mostly related to redundancy and simplicity. So here is a reworked example. See the inline comments for more details:

```js
// Get all the element references you'll need repeated access to just once:
let btnCalc = document.querySelector("button[type='button']");
let btnSubmit = document.querySelector("button[type='submit']");
let form = document.querySelector("form");
let report = document.getElementById("reportingArea");
let rStudent = document.getElementById("rStudent");
let rAverage = document.getElementById("rAverage");
let rLetterGrade = document.getElementById("rLetterGrade");
let gradePercent = document.querySelector("input[name='gradePercent']");
let gradeLetter = document.querySelector("input[name='gradeLetter']");

// No need to set variables for each grade. Just gather all the grade inputs
// up into an Array for easy looping later.
let assignments = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".assign"));

// Don't set variables to properties of elements, set them to the elements
// themselves so that if you decide later you want to look at some other
// aspect of the element, you don't have to query for the same element again later.
var student = document.getElementById('student');
let average =  document.getElementById('average');

// Set up event handlers in JavaScript, not with inline HTML event attributes
// And, you want to do your validation on the form's submit event, not the submit
// button's click event.
btnCalc.addEventListener("click", calculate);
form.addEventListener("reset", function(){
  // Hide the reporting area
  report.classList.add("hidden");
  
  // Show the Calc button and hide the submit button
  btnSubmit.classList.add("hidden");
  btnCalc.classList.remove("hidden");
});

function calculate() {
  const assignmentCount = 4;
  
  rStudent.textContent = student.value;    // Set up the reporting area details
  
  // Loop over the assignments and calculate the average
  let sum = 0;           
  assignments.forEach(function(assign){
    sum += +assign.value;
  });
  
  let average = (sum / assignmentCount).toFixed(2);
  rAverage.textContent = average;
   
  if(average < 59.9){
    rLetterGrade.textContent = "F";
  } else if (average <= 63.9 && average >= 60 ) {
    rLetterGrade.textContent = "D-";
  } else if( average <= 66.9 && average >= 64 ) {
    rLetterGrade.textContent = "D";
  }  else if( average <= 69.9 && average >= 67 ) {
    rLetterGrade.textContent = "D+";
  } else if( average <= 73.9 && average >= 70 ) {
    rLetterGrade.textContent = "C-";
  } else if( average <= 76.9 && average >= 74 ) {
    rLetterGrad.textContente = "C";
  } else if( average <= 79.9 && average >= 77 ) {
    rLetterGrade.textContent = "C+";
  }  else if( average <= 83.9 && average >= 80 ) {
    rLetterGrade.textContent = "B-";
  }  else if( average <= 86.9 && average >= 84 ) {
    rLetterGrade.textContent = "B";
  }  else if( average <= 89.9 && average >= 87 ) {
    rLetterGrad.textContente = "B+";
  }  else if( average <= 93.9 && average >= 90 ) {
    rLetterGrade.textContent = "A";
  }  else {
    rLetterGrade.textContent = "A+";
  }
  
  // Update the hidden form fields
  gradePercent.value = average;
  gradeLetter = rLetterGrade.textContent;  
  
  // Show the reporting area now that it's complete
  report.classList.remove("hidden");
  
  // Show the Submit button and hide the calculate button
  btnSubmit.classList.remove("hidden");
  btnCalc.classList.add("hidden");
}
```

```css
/* All styling should be done with CSS, not in HTML */
.row { margin:.5em 0; }
label { display:inline-block; width:8em; font-weight:bold; }
.assign { width:10em; }
.hidden { display:none; }

/* Styling to show validity status of element */
input:invalid { box-shadow:0 0 1px rgba(255, 0, 0, .5); }
input:valid { box-shadow:0 0 1px rgba(0, 255,0, .5); }
```

```html
<form>
  <!-- A paragraph is for a complete thought or idea, not just to put stuff on its own line.
       A div is for putting stuff on their own line. -->
  <div class="row">
    <!-- Use labels to associate a caption with a form field. -->
    <label for="student">Name: </label>
    <!--
         The default type of an input is text, so you don't need to say it.
         Also, the default size is 20, so you don't need to say that either.
         But, if you do want to style the element, do it with CSS. 
         And, simply add the 'required' attribute to make the field required.
         Also, every form field that will need to send its data to the server
         needs to have a 'name' attribute and value.
    -->
    <input id="student" name="student" required><span class="required">*</span>
  </div>

  <div>
    <label for="assign1">Assignment 1: </label>
    <!-- No need to specify the value="". That's the default. -->
    <input type="number" id="assign1" name="onlynumbers" min="0" max="25" class="assign" required>
    <span class="required">*</span>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <label for="assign2">Assignment 2: </label>
    <input type="number" id="assign2" name="onlynumbers" min="0" max="25" class="assign" required>
    <span class="required">*</span>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <label for="assign3">Assignment 3: </label>
    <input type="number" id="assign3" name="onlynumbers" min="0" max="25" class="assign" required>
    <span class="required">*</span>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <label for="assign4">Assignment 4: </label>
    <input type="number" id="assign4" name="onlynumbers" min="0" max="25" class="assign" required>
    <span class="required">*</span>
  </div>  

  <div class="row">
    <label for="midterm">Midterm Exam: </label>
    <input type="number" id="midterm" name="onlynumbers" min="0" max="100" class="assign" required>
    <span class="required">*</span>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <label for="final">Final Exam: </label>
    <input type="number" id="final"name="onlynumbers" min="0" max="100" class="assign" required>
    <span class="required">*</span>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <label for="project">Final Project: </label>
    <input type="number" id="project" name="onlynumbers" min="0" max="100" class="assign" required>
    <span class="required">*</span>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <button type="button">Calculate</button>
    <button type="submit" class="hidden">Submit</button> <!-- Hidden until you calculate -->
    <input type="reset" value="Reset">
  </div>
  
  <input type="hidden" name="gradePercent">
  <input type="hidden" name="gradeLetter">
</form>

<div id="reportingArea" class="hidden">
  <!-- Instead of writing out largely the same thing over and over with document.writeln
       in JavaScript, just prepare a template area that we can inject the details into.
       We'll keep this section hidden until we're ready to show it. -->
  <h1>
    Hello <span id="rStudent"></span>, your grade percent is <span id="rAverage"></span>% 
    and your letter grade is <span id="rLetterGrade"></span>
  </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Scott, yes, I'm doing this as a regular offline snippet, but how do I loop over the HTML forms in JavaScript? I am very new to JavaScript so I'm not too sure.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really know how to describe it in technical terms, but I meant was that it's basically just a basic code that produces a line that displays name, grade percent and letter grade. I'm just unsure how to validate it. When I take out the JavaScript function, HTML validates all inputs, but when I add in the function, it no longer validates it. I was wondering how to find out how to keep the HTML validation in addition to the function. Thank you for the help

Comment: @Wilson Well, the big issue is that you have a form with a submit button. When the user submits the form, the browser will navigate away from the current page to whatever is specified in the `form` element's `action` attribute and you won't wind up seeing anything you may have updated the page with. Instead, I think you either want an extra button to calculate and show the grade and then a submit button to send that data to the server or just a regular button to do the calculation and no submit button to send the data anywhere. Hold on though - I'm working on a solution.

Comment: Previously, I made a regular button to do the calculation without sending data anywhere. I used  <span id="average"></span>  in my HTML page and it worked, but I wasn't sure how to implement the letter grade into the output. I think that may be the easier option, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @Wilson Ok, take a look at my updated solution and pay close attention to the comments in the HTML, CSS, and JavaScript areas. Notice how much less redundancy is in the code and how much each language is separated from the other.

Comment: @Wilson I've added hidden form fields for the final grade % and the grade letter and those field get populated when you click Calculate so they will be submitted when you submit the form.

Comment: Thank you!! That's exactly what I needed help with. So now I will have 3 separate files, one for HTML, one for JavaScript, and one for CSS right? And I will have to put them together so that it can run on HTML?
This really helps me as a beginner. Thanks again.

Comment: @Wilson You can place them in 3 separate files, but that really only applies if you are going to reuse the CSS or the JavaScript with multiple HTML files. I don't think that applies here, so put all the CSS inside of a `<style></style>` element and place all that in the `<head>` section of the document and place all the JavaScript in a `<script></script>` element and place that down at the bottom of the code, just before the closing `body` tag (`</body>`).

Comment: @Wilson Don't forget to mark this as "the" answer by clicking the check mark at the top left of the answer. Good luck!

Comment: Done! Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score -1):

You can use onBlur event for input. You can use different function depending on the input.

```
<input type="text" onblur="myFunction()">
```

Some more here https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onblur.asp

Comment: This doesn't address how to validate in any way.